# How do I check if someone is logged out of my site with php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I have a database with one of the fields as online and when you log in it changes to yes.. I tried when you press log out it changes to No.. but then that would mean that if they close the tab it would remain online. Does anyone know how to check and then set it to offline by using php preferably.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there's a reliable way to always do this, because the browser isn't required to tell the server when the user closes the tab, closes the browser, unplugs the machine, walks away, turns and watches TV instead, gets hit by a meteor, etc.  Maybe update the table with the user's last activity (on each page request) and have a background process which polls for users with no recent activity (coinciding with session timeout, I imagine) and updates them as no longer being logged in?  Or instead of the process, adjust your query to filter out inactive users.

Comment: PHP wouldn't know if someone has closed a tab or not, you might be able to do it with some sort of JavaScript (onbeforeunload) > Ajax call

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to have implemented all the back-end, you could use AJAX to update it, setting `async` to false is important, or it won't work properly since window is unloading. Assuming you have a PHP file named target.php which does the database updating work, you could do this, using jQuery:

```
$(window).unload( function () {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        async: false  
    });
    $.get("target.php");
});
```

Comment: then where in this do I update the table and set online='No'

Comment: in target.php, obviously.

Comment: That should be the work of `target.php` (PHP part, which perhaps you have already implemented). `target.php` gets called and it will update the db.

Comment: Are you sure this happens after the tab is closed? it didn't work for me

Comment: It should fire whenever page is unloaded.

Comment: it happens as soon as u enter the page, so it basically sets u to offline anyway

Comment: Sorry, but there exists no fool-proof way to detect "tab closing". This event fires on unloading of a window only by navigation.